# How to calculate difference between a value, based on start and end datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using SQL to query a MySQL database. The records show a houses PV energy generation over time. The total PV energy generated is updated every 5 minutes. I have several months worth of data.

| Metric | Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pv_generation_energy | 5634.1 | 2021-10-18 16:45:00 |
| pv_generation_energy | 5623.3 | 2021-10-18 16:40:00 |
| pv_generation_energy | 5622.4 | 2021-10-18 16:35:00 |
| pv_generation_energy | 5619.5 | 2021-10-18 16:30:00 |

How do I calculate the difference between the two values, based on a start and end date, showing the total PV energy generation?

In the instance above, stating a start date of 2021-10-18 16:45:00 and end date of 2021-10-18 16:30:00 would result in a value of 4.6.

Comment: Use 2 copies of the table, each with its own condition by the date, cross join and substract.

Comment: what's the logic for calculating difference?

Comment: isn't it 14.6, instead of 4.6 diff?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subtract values based on another value in same row in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27559014/subtract-values-based-on-another-value-in-same-row-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MAX and MIN you could simply do

```
SELECT MAX(metric) - MIN(metric) as generated
FROM tablename
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2021-10-18 16:30:00' AND '2021-10-18 16:40:00'
```

From you data it generates `14.6` which I think is the correct answer

```
5634.1 - 5619.5 = 14.6
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution works well. My final code, used in Python/MySQL/Flask...

SELECT MAX(`Value`) - MIN(`Value`) AS "GENERATED" FROM `hbb2001` WHERE `Metric` = "pv_generation_energy" AND `timeStamp` BETWEEN "2021-10-12" AND "2021-10-19"

Answer (score 1):

```
select (t1.Value - t2.Value) your_result
from  tbl1 t1 inner join tbl1 t2
on 
t1.Date = '2021-10-18 16:45:00' and 
t2.Date = '2021-10-18 16:30:00'
```

simply join self and minus the values